# Manipulating the Rate Request Object via a ajax call

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping

In my attempt to recalculate shipping rates , I want to pass-in a bunch of parameters to the original rate calculate request.

What would be a best practice in Manipulating the Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request object that is passed in to my shipping module. Below is the code that I am using in my ajax controller to recalculate the shipping.

```
    $params = array('my','parama','to', 'pass');
    $shipping = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that without rewriting some core class.
The `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request` object is created and used locally in the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::requestShippingRates`.

The request object is then used in `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRates()`.
You can rewrite any of the methods above and inject your logic.